# How to install senaite.lims on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: software-installation

I am trying the instructions on [this page](https://www.senaite.com/docs/installation)
but I am running into tons of errors along the line. If anyone managed to install this program on Ubuntu 18.04, I would be happy to see some working instructions.

The instruction were updated and although there are some error messages during installation it seems to work now. This is how the errors look like:

```
Got senaite.jsonapi 1.2.0.
Getting distribution for 'senaite.impress<2.0.0'.
warning: no files found matching '*.rst'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'static'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'src/senaite/impress'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.mo' found under directory 'src/senaite/impress'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'src/senaite/impress/static/js/node_modules'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'src/senaite/impress/static/js/src'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'node_modules'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'src/senaite/impress/locales/.tx'
Got senaite.impress 1.2.2.
Getting distribution for 'senaite.core<2.0.0'.
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'bika'
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/bika/lims/skins/bika/guard_handler.py", line 10
    return wf_guard_handler(context, transition_id)
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/bika/lims/skins/bika/guard_attach_transition.py", line 19
    return False
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/bika/lims/skins/bika/member_is_client.py", line 16
    return 'Clients' in member_groups
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

  File "/home/senaite/buildout-cache/eggs/tmpx_dMCJ/senaite.core-1.3.2-py2.7.egg/bika/lims/skins/bika/guard_attach_transition.py", line 19
    return False
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

  File "/home/senaite/buildout-cache/eggs/tmpx_dMCJ/senaite.core-1.3.2-py2.7.egg/bika/lims/skins/bika/guard_handler.py", line 10
    return wf_guard_handler(context, transition_id)
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

  File "/home/senaite/buildout-cache/eggs/tmpx_dMCJ/senaite.core-1.3.2-py2.7.egg/bika/lims/skins/bika/member_is_client.py", line 16
    return 'Clients' in member_groups
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1191741/edit) your question and include the errors you encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We updated the installation instructions on the official site: https://www.senaite.com/docs/installation

If you still encounter problems, you can also try out the prebuild Docker containers: https://github.com/senaite/senaite.docker/

Comment: `chmod +x Miniconda2-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh` is missing in the instructions.

Comment: Also it should be `conda activate senaite`

Comment: I am getting above errors during installation, but it works!!! I can start senaite.

Comment: You can ignore these errors, these are coming from `setuptools` calling [Restricted Python](https://docs.plone.org/4/en/develop/plone/security/sandboxing.html) files, also see here: https://docs.plone.org/4/en/manage/troubleshooting/buildout.html#buildout-and-syntaxerrors

Comment: The installation instructions are incomplete and only work when you want to run senaite on localhost. There are no instructions how to make it run on a remote server and all paths on the website are hardcoded to localhost.